# Expand template parameters VC++ vs. MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, mingw-w64

A template parameter pack I created needs to be converted to become a pack of a single given type, which is then used for various purposes. I was successful at this using the MinGW-w64 compiler(MSYS2). However, the same code(see below) does not compile with Visual C++ 2015.

```
template<int dimension, typename = std::make_index_sequence<dimension>>
class MyClass;

template <int dimension, std::size_t... Is>
class MyClass<dimension, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    template<typename>
    using toInt = int;

    std::tuple<decltype(Is)...> val1;
    std::tuple<toInt<decltype(Is)>...> val2;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(val1)>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(val2)>::value << std::endl;
    }
};

MyClass<3> obj;

// Should print two times '3'
```

Specifically the following gives a compile error:

```
std::tuple<toInt<decltype(Is)>...> val2;
" '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand "
```

The first tuple where the integer sequence is not converted to ints but is used as a pack of size_ts does compile and work correctly with both compilers.

Why does this happen? Is VC++ wrong/incomplete or did I program incorrectly?

The conversion is not necessarily limited to integers, neither is the pack only used for tuples. This is a simplified example. The complete program also compiles and functions correctly with MinGW.

Comment: Yes it's most probably a bug, it seems MSVC has trouble with the `decltype` in the pack expansion. You can work around it by using a layer of indirection: `template<typename> using toInt2 = int; template<typename... Ts> using toInt = std::tuple<toInt2<Ts>...>; toInt<decltype(Is)...> val2;`

Comment: Does this work for you with VC++? This also gives me a compile error: " '<unnamed-symbol>': pack expansions cannot be used as arguments to non-packed parameters in alias templates ", at " using toInt = std::tuple<toInt2<Ts>...>; ".

Comment: This does work with MinGW though, so I guess a VC++ error.

Comment: Interesting. http://rextester.com/PYEWS53258 does not work on rextester, but it works on webcompiler.cloudapp.net (which is usually the latest version or even a beta).

Comment: I'm going to update my compiler and see what happens.

Comment: Updated to the newest version and the issue is still there sadly.